# Datatable info is lost after i do a flitered search

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm having a problem with a data table, whenever I use the search function in my table all the data is lost the moment I input anything on the search bar, I create this data table dynamically using AJAX, first I do a request to the server to get the data for my table.

```
function traerBecas() {
var ciclo = document.getElementById("ciclo").value;
$.ajax({
    url: '/becas/listaBecas',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        "ciclo": ciclo,
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(response){
        llenarTabla(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Once I get the response as a JSON I pass the info to another function to build each table row and insert it into the table.

```
function llenarTabla(jsonArray) {
var tabla = document.getElementById('becaBody');
tabla.innerHTML = "";

jsonArray.forEach(element => {
    var trElement = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdCLVBECA = document.createElement('td');
    var tdINSTIT = document.createElement('td');
    var tdCICLO= document.createElement('td');
    var tdSECCION = document.createElement('td');
    var tdFECINI = document.createElement('td');
    var tdFECFIN = document.createElement('td');
    var tdACCIONES = document.createElement('td');
    var linkEditar = document.createElement('a');
    var linkEliminar = document.createElement('a');

    tdCLVBECA.innerText = element.CLV_BECA;
    tdINSTIT.innerText = element.INSTIT.toUpperCase();
    tdCICLO.innerText = element.CICLO;
    tdSECCION.innerText = element.SECCION;
    tdFECINI.innerText = element.FEC_INI;
    tdFECFIN.innerText = element.FEC_FIN;
    

    linkEditar.setAttribute("href","/becas/editar/"+element.CLV_BECA);
    linkEditar.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "tooltip");
    linkEditar.setAttribute("data-bs-placement", "top");
    linkEditar.setAttribute("title", "Eliminar");
    linkEditar.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-pen'></i>";

    
    linkEliminar.setAttribute("onclick", "eliminacion("+element.CLV_BECA+")");
    linkEliminar.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "tooltip");
    linkEliminar.setAttribute("data-bs-placement", "top");
    linkEliminar.setAttribute("title", "Editar");
    linkEliminar.innerHTML = "&nbsp;<i class='fas fa-trash'></i>";

    tdACCIONES.appendChild(linkEditar);
    tdACCIONES.appendChild(linkEliminar);
    trElement.appendChild(tdCLVBECA);
    trElement.appendChild(tdINSTIT);
    trElement.appendChild(tdCICLO);
    trElement.appendChild(tdSECCION);
    trElement.appendChild(tdFECINI);
    trElement.appendChild(tdFECFIN);
    trElement.appendChild(tdACCIONES);
    tabla.appendChild(trElement);
    
});
```

}

Then I have the function to transform my table to a data table, and up to this moment, everything works alright. EDIT: Forgot to mention that this info is run first when the page is loaded, the table at the beginning is empty and then is filled with the info I requested.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    language: {
        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json'
    }
    });
});
```

Then, once I have my table built, I try to use the search function that it generates, but then I run into the problem that the table doesn't find the info, loses the data, and doesn't return to the previous state once I delete the prompt on the search bar.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm at a loss of what to do, I have other data tables that don't have this problem, however, those tables aren't built using AJAX, they get their info directly from the controller with the compact() function in the PHP controller, and using Blade directives like @foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

You should open up your browser's dev tools and inspect the network request to your endpoint:

`url: '/becas/listaBecas'`

It could be a number of things, the network tab will show you if there is an error with the AJAX request. If the AJAX request has no error, you will want to look at your endpoint and debug the query that is being run to see why it's not returning any results.

Would also be a good idea to add a error catch for the AJAX call:

```
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("There was an error with the request");
  }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the function to transform the table to a datable is run at the beginning when I load the page, the datable is empty and then filled, would that information change your answer or is that irrelevant?